# Why has my GroupWise stopped auto-completing the "To:" address field?

Tags: email, address-book, groupwise

I used to have auto-completion for addresses in the "To:" field, when sending an email in GroupWise... For some reason, now it doesn't work and I have to bring up the address book each time to add recipients.

I haven't been able to find an option that turns this on or off - does anyone have any ideas why this just stopped working?

Comment: What version of GroupWise?

Comment: GroupWise 7.0.3 Build 1068

On another PC in my office it works fine, and I have no idea what the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since reinstalled the machine, and the problem is gone. Still no idea why it stopped working.